# Ionic integrating Survey Monkey

Tags: ionic-framework, survey, surveymonkey

Am working on an app for surveys using survey Monkey, I wanted to know what experience have you had if you have used survey Monkey for Ionic. Okay this is the solution that i need to work out.

I need to create two surveys. One is weekly and other monthly. If the user hasn't participated in weekly survey, they can't participate in monthly survey, and also the weekly has to persist till its answered.

Any Ideas out here!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Ionic, but if you're building an app then you probably want to use the [SurveyMonkey REST API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/).

One way to do this is to send out emails to recipients to take the survey using [SurveyMonkey's email collector](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-send). If you don't want users to do it from the web application you can programatically do this, something like:

**Create an email collector:**

```
POST /v3/surveys/{id}/collectors
{
    "type": "email"
}
```

**Create a message on that collector:**

```
POST /v3/collectors/{id}/messages
{
    "type": "invite"
}
```

**Add recipients:**

```
POST /v3/collectors/{id}/messages/{id}/recipients/bulk
{
    "contacts": [{
        "email": "test@example.com"
    }, {
        "email": "test2@example.com"
    }]
}
```

**Then send out the email:**

```
POST /v3/collectors/{id}/messages/{id}/send
{}
```

You can then [fetch responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses) filtered by a date range, and then only send out follow up emails to those who responded.

**Fetch responses:**

```
GET /v3/collectors/{id}/responses/bulk?start_created_at=<start_date>&end_created_at=<end_date>
```

The `recipient_id` in the body (also contact information in `metadata`) can be used to identify the user and follow this cycle again for only the emails who responded to the survey.